# popup window to be active

Tags: popupwindow

I have some code like this where in I am trying to open a popup window and want it to be active and the source to not to have any function

```
<a href="window.open("a.html")"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it in this way:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open("a.html")"/>
```

Comment: sorry. <a href="javascript:window.open("a.html")"/>
in that way.

Comment: ha ha thanks for correcting my code.
But my question was i want the popup to be active window untill it is closed not the window from which it originated.
Please see for this one.

Comment: what you want to saw me? you missing the text.

Comment: then you need to open the "grayed-out" window not a normal window. follow this link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/117667/HTML-JavaScript/keeping-pop-up-window-active